# Compare this.state to a function to apply style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a function to filter values.

If I map over the function `filteredMovies`, it removes the genre buttons and movies which do not apply.

However, instead of removing them I want to a custom `className`. I want to apply a different `style` to `<Filter1>` & `<Movies>`. What is the correct way to do this?

I've put this inside a codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/76ZjOyBvA)

Example 1:

## Compare `this.state.movies`

```
  {this.uniqueGenres1(this.state.movies).map(e => (
    <Filter1
      key={e.id}
    />
  ))}
```

## To `filteredMovies`

```
  {this.uniqueGenres1(filteredMovies).map(e => (
    <Filter1
      key={e.id}
    />
  ))}
```

## For the values that do NOT appear in `filteredMovies`, apply a different `className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `className` attribute of React:

```
class Filter1 extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.genre.name);
  };

  render() {
    const { genre, isActive } = this.props;

return (
  <button onClick={this.handleClick} className={isActive? 'active' : 'inactive'}>
    {genre.name}
    {' '}
    <strong>{isActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}</strong>
  </button>
);
```

}
}

Also, don't forget to change 'filteredMovies' to 'movies' in the second map:

```
         <h3> Using filteredMovies function</h3>
  {this.uniqueGenres1(movies).map(e => (
    <Filter1
      key={e.id}
      genre={e}
      isActive={!!selectedFilters[e.name]}
      value={e.type}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  ))}
```

**Update**:

To apply a css style to the `<li>`s rather than hiding them, change the relevant sections in your code to these:

```
class Result extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { result, isActive } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <li className={isActive? 'active' : 'inactive'}>
          {result.name} {' '}
          ({result.genres.map(x => x.name).join(', ')}){' '}
        </li>

      </div>
    );
  }
}


    {movies.map(movie =>  { 
  var isActive = !!filteredMovies.find(filteredrMovie => filteredrMovie.name === movie.name);      
  return (
      <Result key={movie.id} result={movie} isActive={isActive} />
    )
})}
```

It basically uses the JS `find` function to know if a movie from the filtered lists exists in the entire one. Then it passes the result as a prop to the Result component.

**Update2**:

In order to style your buttons based on rather or not they exist in the results rather than if they active:

```
<h3>Using filteredResults function</h3>
        {this.uniqueGenres(filteredResults).map(genre => {
          const isExisting = !!this.uniqueGenres(allFilters).find(
            genre1 => genre1 === genre,
          );
         return (
          <Filter1
            key={genre.id}
            genre={genre}
            isActive={!!selectedFilters[genre.name]}
            isExisting={isExisting}
            onChange={genre.handleChange}
          />
         )})}
```

Replace 'allFilters' with the correct name of the variable that contains the complete list.

**Update3**:

It's working for me now after changing the code of Filter1 component, so it will resolve the className based on 'isExisting':

```
class Filter1 extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.genre);
  };

  render() {
    const { genre, isActive, isExisting } = this.props;

    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className={isExisting ? 'existing' : 'notExisting'}>
        {genre.name}
        {' '}
        <strong>{isActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}</strong>
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks- but I do not want to apply different styles for active/inactive. I want to apply a different style for the ones that `this.state.movies` says exist, but `filteredMovies` says does not exist.

Comment: @Ycon for the <li>s of for the <button>s?

Comment: For both. I want to apply different classNames for the TRUE/FALSE values in both the `<Filter1>` and `<Results>`

Comment: Almost! Thanks. It works for results, but with the filters (buttons) it does not. When I try to map over `this.state.movie` it tells me undefined. Here's the code https://codesandbox.io/s/3OGK2pP9

Comment: @Ycon in which line?

Comment: Line 60- I'd like it to work the same as you showed it for `<Results>`

Comment: @Ycon I don't understant. On what condition do you want to give a different style to the filters? Not based on whether they're active or not?

Comment: Same as with `<Results/>`. If they do not exist in `filteredResults`, apply a different `className`. In plain english- it's a way to show there are no results but NOT hiding it.

Comment: But @Ycon in the movie list you compare the filtered movie list with the full movie list. Here comparing the filtered filter list to the full filter list is equal to check the isActive flag, as I showed you in the first place.

Comment: I don't care if the filter is `active` or not, I only want to apply CSS if it has results in `filteredResults` or `this.state.movies`

Comment: @Ycon I've updated my answer again, but couldn't test it because I didn't know what's the name of the entire genre list. Try to tailor it, and if you don't manage, tell me how to reach the entire genre list and I'll fix my code.

Comment: Nope, now telling me `this5.props.onChange is not a function`. I replaced allFilters as you said. The entire genre list (before filtering) is inside `this.state.movies`. Line 83 https://codesandbox.io/s/3OGK2pP9

Comment: @Ycon I've updated my answer again. Just use the code you most recently posted here, and make the changes in the Filter1 component as I show in my last update.

Comment: Thanks. Something has changed but it still 'hiding' filters when there is no result. It should still show the filter, but apply the `notExisting` css style. https://codesandbox.io/s/3OGK2pP9

Comment: @Ycon it's because you placed my addition to the wrong place. You need to move it to the second <Filter1>.

Comment: Still no- the same. Feel free to update the codesandbox and post the link here https://codesandbox.io/s/3OGK2pP9

Comment: @Ycon I don't know how to save it. Anyway you should switch between 'filteredResults' and 'movies' and it will work.